# issues in html when calling 2 javascript functions at a time

Tags: javascript, html, function, types

I have an HTML file related to a javascript file.
In this javascript file, I have 3 functions which 2 of them will be called `onload` of the body.
These 2 functions are meant to type a string, each of them in a different `textarea`.
But, when Testing this, the two strings that are typed by these js functions, are unreadable
To clarify my issue: the string must be like this:

```
verification step 3 of 4 passed…
enter serial number
```

when I call the 2 functions `onload` of the body, it gives me this:

```
vrfcto  f4pse..
ne eilnme..
```

I can't find the issue in my code.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Webmaster's Top Secret Directory</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="redirector5.js"></script>
</head>
<body background="camouflage.jpg" onload='write()'>
  <div align="center">

     <img src="header.png" alt="Warning"/>

  </div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="container">
     <form name="form1" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
        <div><table align="center" class="table">
<tr><td>
<input type="text" class="inputtext2" name="text" value="open sesame" disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" value="identify yourself...." disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" value="omar saab" disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" value="verification step 1 of 4 passed....  enter secret phrase...." disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" value="i own you terminal. release security now and let me in" disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" value="verifying.... verification step 2 of 4 passed.... enter your purpose of entrance...." disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" value="manage personal files" disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea class="inputtext2222" id='screen' disabled></textarea></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td><textarea class="inputtext2222" id='screen2' disabled></textarea></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" id="myTextarea" autofocus spellcheck="false" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" disabled/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" disabled/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" disabled/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" disabled/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" disabled/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="inputtext2" disabled/></td>
</tr>



</table>
        </div>
        <input 
           type="submit" 
           name="submit">
     </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
if (x === "tango-whisky-70433863") {
  document.location.href = "index6.html";
  return false;
}
else {
  alert('Command not found.\nYou are not supposed to be here.\nGet out now !');
  return false;
}
}

function write(){
type();
type2();
}

var index = 0;
var text = 'verification 3 of 4 passed...';
function type()
{
document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
index += 1;
var t = setTimeout('type()',80);
}

var index = 0;
var text2 = 'enter serial number....';
function type2()
{
document.getElementById('screen2').innerHTML += text2.charAt(index);
index += 1;
var t = setTimeout('type2()',80);
}
```

**NOTE** When I call one of these 2 functions apart, it works.

Comment: change the name of `index` in the 2nd function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think that the issue is with index. You have the same variable name for each type, and when they run at the same time, it confuses the script. You have a variable named index, that will +=1, so when the next function gets it, it is messed up.

Try changing the variable for index on type2() to index2. See if this fixes it.

Comment: Yes it worked by changing the index to index2 thanks

Comment: Sorry but I can't. because Sionnach733 gave me the fix for my issue before you, even it's in a comment. So I have to respect him :/

Comment: I understand. I was typing when he added it, and since it wasn't an answer it didn't alert me that this was answered when I was typing. Didn't notice the quick comment up top. Placeholder for points... lol sneaky.

Comment: Simply, you convinced me. :p

Comment: @WreithKassan I commented first in case there were other underlying problems. The index problem was obvious to me, but there could have been more. you opened your answer with "I could be wrong". I was certain when I posted..

Answer (score 2):

You have tried to declare the variable `index` twice. Try renaming it in the second function and it should work fine.

Explanation:
you declare `var index = 0;` twice within the same scope. in this case the second declaration is what gets used([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ux5zW/)), and so there is only `index` variable inside the functions. That's why each function displays every second letter.